# Jenkins setup using Docker. Not able to install custom tools

Tags: docker, jenkins, plugins

My Jenkins is running as a docker contanier(jenkins/jenkins:lts image). Since I have less number of Jenkins jobs, I am thinking about going for a single node/master only Jenkins deployment. My problem is it is not letting me install any tools using "Custom tools" plugin in master node. I get the error

```
Installer "Extract *.zip/*.tar.gz" cannot be used to install "AnyCustomToolHere" on the node "Jenkins"
```

Is it some access issue of Jenkins user on master node?. Please help. I tried the same on stand-alone installation of Jenkins and it is working without any issues.

Answer (score 8):

I've had the same issue. I found out that I had wrongly configured labels. Each custom tool installed by "Extract *.zip/*.tar.gz" has a label field, from the documentation:

> Optional label to restrict the use of this installation method. This label could be a Label Expression (for example : "linux&&x64" or "windows&&x86"). Only nodes which validate this label (or label expression) will be considered.

When the label does not match the label from an agent the tool is not installed.